# What is the probability that a baseball player hits for the cycle if he gets to bat eight times?

Tags: probability

The question is the following:

> A baseball player is said to “hit for the cycle” if he has a single, a double, a triple, and a home run all in one game. Suppose these four types of hits have probabilities $1/16, 1/4, 1/5,$ and $1/24$. What is the probability of hitting for the cycle if he gets to bat eight times?

[The full Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW3CW.png)

Some people said that my procedure and the answer is wrong.

### I tried to do it like the following. Did I go wrong somewhere?

**The way I proceeded**

Given that,

P(Single)= $\frac{1}{16}$

P(Double)= $\frac{1}{4}$

P(Triple)= $\frac{1}{5}$

P(Home Run) = $\frac{1}{24}$

As there are $4$ types of hits, so the value of $r$ would be $4$.

Here,

$r=4,  n=8$

$\therefore$ The probability of hitting for the cycle if he gets to bat for $8$ times is,
\begin{align*}
P(x=8) & = {8\choose4}\hspace{.1cm} \cdot P(\text{Single}) \cdot P(\text{Double}) \cdot P(\text{Triple}) \cdot P(\text{Home run})\\
& =\hspace{.1cm}{8\choose 4}\hspace{.1cm} \cdot \frac{1}{16} \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{24}\\
& =\frac{70}{7680}\\
& \hspace{.1cm}\equiv 0.91\%
\end{align*}

[My process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDiT0.jpg)

Comment: Please type your question rather than posting a link to an image.  Links can get broken and images cannot be searched.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks for the tutorial. I have edited the question. Please give a look through it.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect since the baseball player could hit more than one single or more than one double or more than one triple or more than one home run.  My inclination would be to try to apply the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle here.  Welcome to MathSE.

Comment: Yes this probability counts also e.g. the chances of hitting for the cycle and having an extra triple in 8 at bats.   But I think the answer given is correct in spirit - this is the probability he hits for a cycle (or better).

Comment: So which one should i consider correct my one, or should I use the Inclusion-Exclusion Method as @N.F.Taussig said?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that the baseball players hits for the cycle is found by subtracting the probability that he obtains no singles or no doubles or no triples or no home runs from $1$.

Let $S$ be the event that he hits at least one single.

Let $D$ be the event that he hits at least one double.

Let $T$ be the event that he hits at least one triple.

Let $H$ be the event that he hits at least one home run.

The probability that the baseball player hits for the cycle in eight plate appearances is
$$\Pr(\text{hits for cycle}) = 1 - \Pr(S' \cup D' \cup T' \cup H')$$
where
\begin{align*}
& \Pr(S' \cup D' \cup T' \cup H')\\
& \quad = \Pr(S') + \Pr(D') + \Pr(T') + \Pr(H')\\
& \qquad - \Pr(S' \cap D') - \Pr(S' \cap T') - \Pr(S' \cap H') - \Pr(D' \cap T') - \Pr(D' \cap H') + \Pr(T' \cap H')\\
& \quad\qquad + \Pr(S' \cap D' \cap T') + \Pr(S' \cap D' \cap H') + \Pr(S' \cap T' \cap H') + \Pr(D' \cap T' \cap H')\\
& \qquad\qquad - \Pr(S' \cap D' \cap T' \cap H')
\end{align*}
We are given the probabilities
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\text{single}) & = \frac{1}{16}\\
\Pr(\text{double}) & = \frac{1}{4}\\
\Pr(\text{triple}) & = \frac{1}{5}\\
\Pr(\text{home run}) &=  \frac{1}{24}
\end{align*}
for a plate appearance.

$\Pr(S')$:  Since $\Pr(\text{single}) = \frac{1}{16}$, the probability of not obtaining a single in a plate appearance is
$$\Pr(\text{no single}) = 1 - \frac{1}{16} = \frac{15}{16}$$
Assuming independence, the probability of not obtaining a single in eight plate appearances is
$$\Pr(S') = \left(\frac{15}{16}\right)^8$$

By similar reasoning,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(D') & = \left(1 - \frac{1}{4}\right)^8 = \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^8\\
\Pr(T') & = \left(1 - \frac{1}{5}\right)^8 = \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^8\\
\Pr(H') & = \left(1 - \frac{1}{24}\right)^8 = \left(\frac{23}{24}\right)^8
\end{align*}

Next, we note that for a plate appearance, the events single, double, triple, and home run are mutually exclusive.

$\Pr(S' \cap D')$:  Since the events single and double are mutually exclusive, the probability of obtaining a single or a double in a plate appearance is
$$\Pr(\text{single} \cup \text{double}) = \Pr(\text{single}) + \Pr(\text{double}) = \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{5}{16}$$
Hence, the probability of obtaining neither a single nor a double in a plate appearance is
$$\Pr(\text{neither a single nor a double}) = 1 - \frac{5}{16} = \frac{11}{16}$$
Thus, the probability of obtaining neither a single nor a double in eight plate appearances is
$$\Pr(S' \cap D') = \left(\frac{11}{16}\right)^8$$
By similar reasoning,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(S' \cap T') & = \left(1 - \frac{1}{16} - \frac{1}{5}\right)^8 = \left(1 - \frac{21}{80}\right)^8 = \left(\frac{59}{80}\right)^8\\
\Pr(S' \cap H') & = \left(1 - \frac{1}{16} - \frac{1}{24}\right)^8 = \left(1 - \frac{5}{48}\right)^8 = \left(\frac{43}{48}\right)^8\\
\Pr(D' \cap T') & = \left(1 - \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5}\right)^8 = \left(1 - \frac{9}{20}\right)^8 = \left(\frac{11}{20}\right)^8\\
\Pr(D' \cap H') & = \left(1 - \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{24}\right)^8 = \left(1 - \frac{7}{24}\right)^8 = \left(\frac{17}{24}\right)^8\\
\Pr(T' \cap H') & = \left(1 - \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{24}\right)^8 = \left(1 - \frac{29}{120}\right)^8 = \left(\frac{91}{120}\right)^8
\end{align*}

$\Pr(S' \cap D' \cap T')$:  Since the events single, double, and triple are mutually exclusive, the probability of obtaining a single, double, or triple in a plate appearance is
$$\Pr(\text{single} \cup \text{double} \cup \text{triple}) = \Pr(\text{single}) + \Pr(\text{double}) + \Pr(\text{triple}) = \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} = \frac{41}{80}$$
Thus, the probability of obtaining neither a single nor a double nor a triple in a plate appearance is
$$\Pr(\text{neither a single nor a double nor a triple}) = 1 - \frac{41}{80} = \frac{39}{80}$$
Hence, the probability of obtaining no singles, doubles, or triples in eight plate appearances is
$$\Pr(S' \cap D' \cap T') = \left(\frac{39}{80}\right)^8$$
By similar reasoning,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(S' \cap D' \cap H') & = \left(1 - \frac{1}{16} - \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{24}\right) = \left(1 - \frac{17}{48}\right)^8 = \left(\frac{31}{48}\right)^8\\
\Pr(S' \cap T' \cap H') & = \left(1 - \frac{1}{16} - \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{24}\right)^8 = \left(1 - \frac{73}{240}\right)^8 = \left(\frac{167}{240}\right)^8\\
\Pr(D' \cap T' \cap H') & = \left(1 - \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{24}\right)^8 = \left(1 - \frac{59}{120}\right)^8 = \left(\frac{61}{120}\right)^8
\end{align*}

$\Pr(S' \cap D' \cap T' \cap H')$:  Since the four events are mutually exclusive, the probability of obtaining a hit in a single plate appearance is
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\text{single} \cup \text{double} \cup \text{triple} \cup \text{home run}) & = \Pr(\text{single}) + \Pr(\text{double} + \Pr(\text{triple}) + \Pr(\text{home run})\\
      & = \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{24}\\
      & = \frac{133}{240}
\end{align*}
Hence, the probability of not getting a hit in a plate appearance is
$$\Pr(\text{neither a single nor a double nor a triple nor a home run}) = 1 - \frac{133}{240} = \frac{107}{240}$$
Hence, the probability that a player does not get a hit in eight plate appearances is
$$\Pr(S' \cap D' \cap T' \cap H') = \left(\frac{107}{240}\right)^8$$
Therefore, the probability that a player hits for the cycle in eight plate appearances is
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\text{hits for cycle}) & = 1 - \left(\frac{15}{16}\right)^8 - \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^8 - \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^8 - \left(\frac{23}{24}\right)^8\\
& \quad + \left(\frac{11}{16}\right)^8 + \left(\frac{59}{80}\right)^8 + \left(\frac{43}{48}\right)^8 + \left(\frac{11}{20}\right)^8 + \left(\frac{17}{24}\right)^8 + \left(\frac{91}{120}\right)^8\\
& \qquad - \left(\frac{39}{80}\right)^8 - \left(\frac{31}{48}\right)^8 - \left(\frac{167}{240}\right)^8 - \left(\frac{61}{120}\right)^8\\
& \quad\qquad + \left(\frac{107}{240}\right)^8
\end{align*}

The numbers used in this problem are rather unrealistic.  Triples are rare events.  The [most triples hit in a season](https://www.baseball-reference.com/leaders/3B_season.shtml) in Major League Baseball is $36$ by Owen Wilson in the year 1912 C.E. and it took him $643$ plate appearances to do it.  Since hitting a triple is a rare event, hitting for the cycle is a still rarer event.  In fact, [no Major League Baseball player has hit for the cycle more than three times in his entire career](https://www.baseball-almanac.com/feats/feats16d.shtml).

Comment: thanks. Right after you told me that I have to use the inclusion exclusion method I have Solved the problem liked the way you solved. Again, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

My first answer is wrong, actually! It counts 12340001 as 2 separate cases, yet calculates the total possible ways assuming they are the same!

So, actually you DO need to use inclusion exclusion, which will be fun...
A = no single occurs, B = no double occurs, C = no triple occurs, D = no home run occurs
(All above assume 8 at-bats)

$$
1-P(A\cup B\cup C\cup D)= 1-(P(A) + P(B) + P(C) + P(D) - P(A\cap B) - P(A\cap C) - P(A\cap D) - P(B\cap C) - P(B\cap D) - P(C\cap D) + P(A\cap B\cap C) + P(A\cap B\cap D) + P(A\cap C\cap D) + P(B\cap C\cap D) - P(A\cap B\cap C\cap D))
$$
Notice the alternative +/-.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).